# Debian Package SBT with timestamp

Tags: scala, debian, sbt

I am new to Scala and SBT, but I came across the JDebPackaging plugin, which appears to be based on the JDeb java plugin.

I want to be able to do `snapshotExpand=true`, which is done in maven like this:

```
<snapshotExpand>true</snapshotExpand>
```

Can anyone help me do the same in SBT?

Update:
I am using the following

```
plugins.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.3")

build.sbt
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
enablePlugins(JDebPackaging)
```

What we want, is to be able to timestamp the debian package. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Why are you not using sbt-native-packager? Now it is standard plugin for packaging scala applications.

Comment: Thanks for the response Denis. I've added some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around with the following function:

```
version := "0.1." + timestamper()

def timestamper() = {
  val today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").format(today)
}
```

if anyone has a better solution then let know